# External iFrame inside a pyramid project. No refresh when its updated

Tags: python, google-chrome, iframe, refresh, pyramid

we include an iFrame inside a pyramid webpage.
The iFrame is a local html file which is not a pyramid webpage.

Everytime the HTML contents (=the iFrame) gets updated and I refresh or load the pyramid webpage with the iFrame again, the iFrame contents do not get updated. If I force a refresh with my browser then the iFrame has the new contents.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you give us ... a Link? Some Code? Something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, firstly, the question has no relation to Python or Pyramid whatsoever - Pyramid just generated you a blob of text which happened to be a HTML page. After that everything is happening in the browser - I suppose your "other page" has HTTP headers which say that the browser does not need to reload it each time and may cache it.

If you want to force reload of the "other" page each time the "pyramid page" is generated, you may try tricking the browser into thinking you want to load a new page each time. To do that, just add a bogus url parameter with some random number:

```
<iframe src="http://other.domain.com/somepage.html?blah=1452352235"></iframe>
```

where the number after blah= may be a timestamp or just a random number.